# Hybris - hmchistoryentries table doesn't exist in 1808 version

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

While doing system update ( or ant update system), we are getting below error (**hmchistoryentries** doesn't exist). Any one faced this before?
Per documentation, it seems this is a deprecated item type. Though we are not using hmc, we are not sure which extension is using this itemtype. Appreciate your help.

`[java] Caused by: org.apache.ddlutils.DatabaseOperationException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hybrisD2C.hmchistoryentries' doesn't exist[java]  at org.apache.ddlutils.platform.PlatformImplBase.readModelFromDatabase(PlatformImplBase.java:1891)[java]    at org.apache.ddlutils.platform.PlatformImplBase.readModelFromDatabase(PlatformImplBase.java:1869)[java]    at de.hybris.bootstrap.ddl.HybrisSchemaGenerator.update(HybrisSchemaGenerator.java:225)[java]   at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization.initializeSchemaAndTypeSystemFullyNewStyle(Initialization.java:1245)[java]    at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization.initialize(Initialization.java:1121)[java]    at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization.createEmptySystemOrUpdate(Initialization.java:776)[java]  at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization.access$4(Initialization.java:756)[java]   at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization$4.call(Initialization.java:563)[java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization$4.call(Initialization.java:1)[java]   at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization$SessionRecoveryAfterRegistryStartupAwareExecutor.execute(Initialization.java:698)[java]   at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization.doInitializeImpl(Initialization.java:566)[java]   at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization.access$5(Initialization.java:488)[java]   at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization$5.call(Initialization.java:812)[java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization$5.call(Initialization.java:1)[java]   at de.hybris.platform.core.system.InitializationLockHandler.performLocked(InitializationLockHandler.java:80)[java]  at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization.doInitialize(Initialization.java:844)[java]   at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.InitPlatformAntPerformableImpl.performImpl(InitPlatformAntPerformableImpl.java:106)[java]     at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.AbstractAntPerformable.doPerform(AbstractAntPerformable.java:92)[java]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[java]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[java]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[java]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[java]   at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:131)[java]     at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Reflect.java:77)[java]    at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:852)[java]   at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:69)[java]  ... 16 more`

Comment: Did you upgrade from an older Hybris (with HMC) to a newer Hybris (without HMC)?

Comment: Yes. Upgraded from 6.3 to 1808. Both versions do not have hmc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you search all *-items.xml files to find out what extension it is coming from? You might also want to check your the localextensions.xml file if the extension or any extension depending on it is there. If it's there, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened due to the incorrect version of DB connector. We were using MySQL 8.0 and *mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar* connector. But SAP officially doesn't support MySQL 8.0 with 1808 version. After downgrading it to MySql 5.x and *mysql-connector-java-5.1.x-bin.jar*, this error no longer exists.

Thank you.